# keyboard shortcut over vnc not working

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, vnc

I'm not sure if my issue is with linux or vnc or both.  I'm running on a system with centos which I'm VNCing into.  I want to be able to toggle between windows inside the linux box, but I want alt-tab to still work on my home desktop as well.  Previously I fixed this by going into keyboard shortcuts and setting the "move between windows, using a popup window" hotkey to "alt-q", which I've learned to use as my linux toggle key.

This worked fine on my old box, but I just switched over to a new box.  I do the same steps, when I'm able to set the shortcut in keyboard shortcuts.  However, the shortcut doesn't actually work.

I think that they key stroke "alt+q" is getting through VNC, or else I wouldn't be able to set it in keyboard shortcuts.  However, if that's the case I don't know why centos doesn't just work.  do I need to restart some service that handles hotkeys to detect the changes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out this now works.  I don't know what I changed, but I had restarted my VNCServer.  Perhaps it required a full gnome reboot to detect the change?